# Is it possible to build a custom google cloud image based on windows?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I need to create a google compute engine image based on windows 7, there is detailed documentation on building images for google compute engine but it looks like it mostly geared towards Linux distributions. Is it possible to build a windows custom instance like a windows 7 one based on a current installation I am running say on virtual box or any other virtualization for that matter ?

Answer (score 2):

Google Compute Engine does not support running custom Windows images.  The only way to run Windows is to start with an existing image, and create snapshots and images from there.  So Windows 7, in particular, is not presently supported.

I'm sure it's not the answer you wanted to hear.  :-(  But it is accurate.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, I was looking for a super hero answer like, 'we have setup windows 7 on google compute engine and here are the steps' . Thanks though I havent been able to get it running even using the conversion steps of raw disk to an image the way they explain for line, just hope one day they do something similar for windows images.

Comment: When you say GCE doesn't support running custom Windows images, what do you mean?

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-os-image

Comment: Lingnik, the instructions in the link show how to take a running GCE instance and create an image.  You can use that image to create more GCE instances.  However, there is no way to upload a custom VM image.  For example, running Windows 10.

Comment: @Lingnik yes Jeffrey Explanation above is what I had in mind, like working from a windows 7 iso image I have and using it to build a new image for google compute engine, that seems not to be possible, there are instructions for doing this for linux but now windows.

Comment: I have the same the problem today, is there any changes on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO, but there is a workaround. I don't have complete answer yet but theoretically its doable.

1. Create compute engine instance containing Ubuntu VM
2. Download and install virtual box inside that VM
3. Download and install windows inside the Virtual Box

If you need GUI version of Ubuntu, you can follow this link https://medium.com/google-cloud/graphical-user-interface-gui-for-google-compute-engine-instance-78fccda09e5c

or start a headless VM using this link 
http://xmodulo.com/how-to-create-and-start-virtualbox-vm-without-gui.html

Answer (score -1):

Google's documentation on building Windows images for GCE is here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-os-image

You can also create an image from scratch by uploading a disk: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images

Comment: The explanation for uploading a disk seems to be only for Linux but not windows.

Comment: Links provided are irrelevant to the customer's issue